# Angular JS tutorial bootstrapping 2

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I am just following the tutorial listed on Angular JS, I am using Windows platform. I am on the bootstrapping page, I am stuck at app running; I have installed node JS and downloaded GitBash; when I opened command prompt and type node scripts\web-server.js in c:\users\supersonicseattle>; This appear:

```
Error: Cannot find module ' C:\users\supersonicseattle\scripts\web-server.js'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename <module.js:338:15>
  at Function.Module._load <module.js:280:25>
  at Function.Module.runMain <module.js:497:10>
  at startup<module.js:119:16>
  at node.js:901:3
```

In addition, I am unable to open designated html local host in the internet browser, it always contains error.

Please help. Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: does that file exist?  Also try `.\scripts\web-server.js`

Answer (score 0):

Typically the directory c:\users\ is your user home directory - are you logged in as user name supersonicseattle? If so, you don't want to create your project there, you want to create it one level down.

Have you cloned the git repository yet? It so, it's probably one level down from the directory you're trying to run from.

Comment: I have cloned the git repository as instructed in the tutorial using gitbash. When I search the file for angular js, it shows that the file is in c:\superonicseattle. Also, I have tried entering .\scripts\web-server.js as suggested by Nirk. Could you also show me how to go one level down the directory. Many thanks.